# Was HTML first implemented using SGML?

Tags: html, sgml

This is a question from a past exam paper.

HTML was *first* impelmented using
1. C++
2. Java
3. Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML)
4. none of the above

I think the answer to it is SGML because here on this link (https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/HTMLandSGML.html), it says "HTML is an application conforming to International Standard ISO 8879 -- Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML)"

the answer could very well be "none of the above" but I'm not sure. I have tried to google it but have not hit gold yet.

Can someone please confirm how was HTML *first* implemented?

Comment: surely it's none of the above? It's own markup language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia entry for SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language):

> While HTML was developed partially independently and in parallel with
> SGML, its creator, Tim Berners-Lee, intended it to be an application
> of SGML.[citation needed] The design of HTML (Hyper Text Markup
> Language) was therefore inspired by SGML tagging, but, since no clear
> expansion and parsing guidelines were established, most actual HTML
> documents are not valid SGML documents.
>
> Later, HTML was reformulated
> (version 2.0) to be more of an SGML application, however, the HTML
> markup language has many legacy- and exception- handling features that
> differ from SGML's requirements.
>
> HTML 4 is an SGML application that
> fully conforms to ISO 8879 – SGML.[14]

So the answer is that while it was first implemented using SGML-type markup, but it was in parallel rather than as a direct decendant of SGML.

Further, on the same article, the World Wide Web Consortium states:

> The charter for the 2006 revival of the World Wide Web Consortium HTML Working Group says, **"the Group will not assume that an SGML parser is used for 'classic HTML'"**.[15] Although HTML syntax closely resembles SGML syntax with the default reference concrete syntax, HTML5 abandons any attempt to define HTML as an SGML application, explicitly defining its own parsing rules,[16] which more closely match existing implementations and documents. It does, however, define an alternative XHTML serialization, which conforms to XML and therefore to SGML as well.

*(my emphesis)*

Therefore the answer is clearly "No - none of the above". XML can be classed as a SGML markup but HTML 1 is not, HTML 2 is, HTML 3 and 4 are not and HTML 5 uses it's own markup.

Time spent reading Wikipedia: 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already cited the authoritative resource on the subject (mirrored at W3C's web site): according to the [very first web site in existence](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html), and the [Technical - HTML Format subsection linked from it](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/SGML.html), HTML was indeed specified as an application of SGML. However, [the first web browser was *implemented* in Objective-C](https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/WorldWideWeb.html), so I think *4. None of the above* is the correct answer.